# My system always enter emergency mode when booting

Tags: linux, boot, thinkpad

My deepin20 machine always enter into emergency mode when booting. Then, in order to be able to return into normale mode i have to type
`mount -a` and `exit`.

I started encountering this problem after I created a partition on the disk in which my account home is.

Is there a way to solve this tedious problem or at least some trick to automatically make my system execute `mount -a` when booting?

Answer (score 0):

Your system enter probably the emergency mode because of a serious error. While in emergency mode, check which partition are mounted and check the options used. You will probable find an important partition not available to mount. Check /etc/fstab. Perhaps /etc/fstabs use UUID entries and an UUID has been changed while you have worked on the partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i managed to solve the error by executing `fsck -AR -y`  by the emergency mode terminal. Then i have been able to boot back into normale mode.

It seams I just had some problem with a partition.